# Jquery check if user is at bottom not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code that checks if the user hits the bottom of the page, but it does not seem to work correctly, and i cant figure out what the problem is....

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var load = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
              if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                alert("test");
              }
            });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: This is just a typo, `scollTop` should be `scrollTop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `$(document).height() - $(window).height()` there is always going to be a minor difference atleast in firefox, my current browser.

try the following code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("test");
   }
});
```

Works on all browsers.

Thanks,
Paras

Answer (score 0):

typo in the code ...if($(window).scollTop() ...

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var load = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
              if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                alert("test");
              }
            });
        });
      </script>
```

also do you have a fixed navbar which may be throwing off the offset?

Comment: It still does not seem to work.... I have a "include("menubar.php") in my file

Comment: the reason I ask is that if it is fixed, you will have padding on the body, and so will have to add that into your calculation for determining the scroll position.

Comment: How do i calculate it then if i have like 50px padding or something?

Comment: no idea - but try...var offset=50; ...$(document).height() - ($(window).height()+offset);... or something. I am sure you will be able to research the correct terminology / logic.